# Is there a way of running nodejs browser automation on Android?

Tags: android, node.js, apk, browser-automation

It doesn't matter if it's headless or not, is it possible to execute browser automation written in Nodejs on Android eg. puppeteer, nightmare etc? I suppose it might be possible by manually installing nodejs on android but if there's a simpler way to execute or even port nodejs app to android apk then I'd really appreciate some light on this.

Comment: Good luck for installing Nodejs on an android device. Maybe you can integrate automation tests directly in your app? Something like a _is my app ok ?_ button.

Comment: u ll have to root your device for that. because you have to install certain binaries to run nightmare and all